# In Qualtrics, how to hide a slider from being displayed until a response is given?

Tags: slider, survey, qualtrics

I'm trying to create a survey containing several slider-type questions, asking participants to select a point on a line to indicate their experience of different emotions. For example:

*Not at all anxious -----------------------|---------------------Extremely anxious*

These questions are meant to serve as visual analogue scales (VAS), often used in my field but typically administered via paper/pen. A digital VAS would be very useful for my research, but I have 2 problems with the Qualtrics format.

First, I need to hide the vertical slider until participants selects a point on the line (in effect removing any visual "starting point" that can influence responses). Second, I can't force participants to respond to every question, so I need a way to distinguish those who skip a question/don't answer (including code to check if the slider was displayed or not displayed when the participant chooses to continue to the next question might work, so that Qualtrics stores no response for that question if the slider is still hidden).

Thanks for the help! I'm not a coder, so I would really value any and all advice!

Comment: A Qualtrics slider question isn't really a good match for what you are trying to do.  Take a look at a bipolar matrix question to see if that meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Bipolar matrix does look like it would solve some issues, but most importantly, I need to have participants responding on a continuum (rather than selecting predetermined points on a scale). This is why I hoped to use the slider. It gives us more variance in responses, which is really helpful in this context.